# How to understand the restriction of forms on submanifold (Page 216 on Tu's book)?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

On Tu's 'Introduction to Manifolds' (2nd edition, here is a link: [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xQsTJJGsgs4C&q=225#v=snippet&q=225&f=false) ), page 216 (a correction on Page 216: 'regular submanifold' should be changed to 'immersed submanifold'), he said: If $S$ is a smooth curve on $R^2$ defined by the non-constant function $f(x,y)$, then $df=(\partial f /\partial x) dx+(\partial f /\partial y)dy$ is non-zero 1 form on $R^2$, but since $f$ is zero on $S$, $df$ is also zero on $S$.

Here is my understanding for why $df$ is zero on $S$:

For a fixed point $p=(a,b)$ on $S$, by definition of the 'restriction of forms to a submanifold' on the book (P216 and P197), we have $(df|_s)_p(X)=(df)_p(X^*)$, where the $X$ is a tangent vector in $T_pS$

(Besides, I think the $X$ on the LHS is in the $T_pS$, while the $X^*$ on the RHS is the image of the $X$ by inclusion $i_*:T_pS \rightarrow T_pR^2$. So I denote the image as $X^*= i_*(X)$... I'm not sure whether I'm correct...).

By definition on Page 191 and Page 87, $(df)_p(X^*)=X^*_pf=(i_*(X))_pf=X_p(f\circ i )$, and since $f\circ i$ is identically $0$ on $S$, $X_p$ is a tangent vector on the $S$, therefore $X_p=0$, which means $df = 0$ on $S$.

So whether my understanding is correct??? Thanks!

Comment: your reasoning seems right